# Not able to write nsdata in a folder

Tags: ios, nsdata, writetofile

Below is the Code:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];                

 [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                            if(error != nil)
 NSLog(@"write error %@", error);
```

error:

```
 write error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x8b7b850 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8b7d7c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/alfa-1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/C24B228A-599E-4249-97A7-17775E8A546B/Library/Caches/ChannelListImages/http:/direct.domain.com/files/icons/1-all-cb.jpg, NSUserStringVariant=Folder}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to create the intermediate folders...

Comment: show your savedImagePath in NSLog. The path may be invalid

Comment: what is intermediate folder?

Comment: if the path is /folderA/folderB/folderC. folderA and folderB would be intermediate folders. If you want to save in folderC folderA, B and C must exist to save something there.

Comment: @MohammedEbrahim what is savedImagePath?

Comment: Maybe you should read the error message.  It's unlikely that you have a directory named "http:".  (But I didn't down-vote because you actually did include the error message, which is good.)

Answer (score 5):

Before writing the data to file. You need to create the folder. follow these steps

```
#define APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY @"Application Data"
+ (NSString *)cachesDirectoryPath
// Returns the path to the caches directory.  This is a class method because it's
// used by +applicationStartup.
{
    NSString *      result;
    NSArray *       paths;

    result = nil;
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ( (paths != nil) && ([paths count] != 0) ) {
        assert([[paths objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
        result = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    result = [result stringByAppendingPathComponent:APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:result]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:result withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
    }

    return result;
}
```

after this: `#define kPhotosDirectoryName @"ApplicationDocuments"`

```
    NSMutableString *savePath = [NSMutableString string];
    [savePath appendFormat:@"%@/%@",[YOURClass cachesDirectoryPath],kPhotosDirectoryName];

    [savePath appendFormat:@"/%@",YOUR_FILE_NAME];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]) {
        //write the data to file here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample. It works for me.

Declare -(NSString*) datafilepath in .h file

```
-(NSString *) datafilepath{
NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documents=[path objectAtIndex:0];
return [documents stringByAppendingFormat:@"/sample.plist"];
}
```

Anywhere u want to perform write function

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];                
[imageData writeToFile:[self datafilepath]atomically:YES];
 if(error != nil)
 NSLog(@"write error %@", error);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: It should be [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.plist"];